# Soundcloud python OAuth error

Tags: python, oauth, soundcloud

This should be a fairly simple Python app which uses OAuth to authenticate itself with the soundclodu API. It follows very closely the code for the official library: https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python

When I load my app, I get sent to the soundcloud login page, which then re-directs me to /user with the code query string.

However, it fails at the part where I attempt to obtain the access token,etc...

This is the error I get:

```
 File "/Users/asselinpaul/Dropbox/UPENN/SPRING15/CIS192/final_project/server.py", line 19, in user
            code = request.args.get('code'))
 TypeError: 'Resource' object is not iterable
```

I'm pretty sure this just means that client.exchange_token is returning a 401 error (this is what happens when I try to print client.exchange_token(code = request.args.get('code')).

Code:

```
    import soundcloud
    from flask import Flask, redirect, request

    app = Flask(__name__)

    client = soundcloud.Client(
            client_id="*****************************",
            client_secret="*****************************",
            redirect_uri='http://127.0.0.1:5000/user'
        )

    @app.route('/')
    def hello_world():
        return redirect(client.authorize_url())

    @app.route('/user')
    def user():
        access_token, expires, scope, refresh_token = client.exchange_token(
            code = request.args.get('code'))
        return ("Hi There, %s" % client.get('/me').username)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar application (exactly the same, basically) and when I run it I get an error that says:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'args'
```

As far as I can tell, because request.py in the soundcloud module uses urllib this is probably an issue with python 2.x versus python 3.x. I am using python 3 which I don't think can use urllib. I'd love to have a better answer or a real solution, but this is just what I've gathered.